# Make link open on card click

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I'm making a website in HTML. It's mostly formed of cards, and some of the cards link to other pages (for example, a biography). I want some of my cards, upon click, to take me to another webpage. I have a card class:

```
.card {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        transition: 0.3s;
            border-radius: 10px;

            width: 70%;
            margin: auto;
    }
```

And another class to make the card look nice:

```
.card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
```

So when the mouse hovers over certain cards, the card's shadow increases. These are the cards I want to have links (only two so far). Other non-link cards have a different class.

**Is there a way to make the cards using the `card` class to link to another page when clicked?** It should be if there's a click anywhere on the card, not just the text.

Comment: You can do that with html <a href="link">card content</a> tag or jQuery , but not with CSS. Add some html code

Comment: @wpcoder <a> tag?

Comment: @wpcoder So I can simply enclose the entire card in the <a> tag?

Comment: @wpcoder Worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do wrap the `<a>` tag around the card content but you need to add another class around the tag or else the areas to the sides can be clicked. This keeps it just to the card.

```css
.card {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 100%;
 }

 .card:hover { box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
    
 .control-width { width: 70%; margin: auto; }
 
 .card2 {
      box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 70%;
 }

 .card2:hover { box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }
```

```html
<div class="control-width">
    <a href="your-link-bio">
      <div class="card">
      <h1>Card Header</h1>
      <h3>Card Sub Header</h3>
      <p>Card Description Card Description Card DescriptionCard DescriptionCard Description<p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>


 <a href="your-link-bio">
   <div class="card2">
     <h1>Card Header</h1>
     <h3>Card Sub Header</h3>
     <p>Card Description Card Description Card DescriptionCard DescriptionCard Description<p>
   </div>
 </a>
```

Comment: This makes the card smaller.

Comment: Just change the width in the class control-width then to the desired width you want. width: 100%; or width: 700px; etc.

Comment: No, it makes the _card_ smaller. 70% is the right size. I think it's the <div> enclosing it that makes the card smaller.

Comment: Do you still have the 70% width on the card class? I updated the code above and you can see how the hover is effected with vs without the control-width class wrapped around the `<a>`. Also both cards are the same size in the above example too.